# How to rotate the app along with content playing in UWP web app?

Tags: javascript, uwp, rotation

I want to rotate the app screen in portrait mode along with content in UWP javascript app.

I have applied the following code but no success.

```
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.autoRotationPreferences = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayOrientations.portrait;
```

Kindly let me know what wrong I am doing with it?

Comment: The DisplayOrientations values describe the orientation of the display or monitor and not necessarily the orientation of your app. To determine the orientation of your app for layout purposes, use the [ApplicationView.Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.orientation#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_Orientation) property.

Comment: Actually, I was testing orientation in desktop and for orientation, accelerator needs to be there but in desktop, it's not there, that's why I was unable to deduct orientation change practically.

By the way thanks for the information.

Comment: You're right. In general, desktop doesn't have accelerator. Have a good day!